# I have written palindrome code in java using StringBuilder class but it not working?

Tags: java

I have written a code for checking palindrome but it is showing all inputs as a palindrome

```
class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String a = "shubham", reverse="";
  StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();

  input.append(a);

  System.out.println("Value of a:-"+a);
  System.out.println("Value of b:-"+input.reverse().toString());

  if(a.equals(input.reverse().toString())) {
      System.out.println("Given input is palidrome");
  }
  else {
      System.out.println("Given input is not palidrome");
  }
}
```

The output of the above is:

> Value of a:-shubham
>   Value of b:-mahbuhs
>   Given input is palidrome

Comment: How not working ? COuld you give an example for which it doesn't give the expected output ?

Comment: Yes its not giving expected output

Comment: You are reversing it twice

Comment: Thanks Aniket. i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder.reverse()` is a stateful operation, meaning that `input.reverse() == input` will be `true`. (it simply returns `this`)

So when you reverse to print it and then later on reverse it again for your comparison, it will be in its initial position. Meaning that it will equal to `a`.

When you remove the print statements it will work. Or if you want to print it, then simply remove the `reverse()` call in the `if`-statement:

```
if (a.equals(input.toString()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `reverse` operation applies on the object itself, it does not return a modified copy

```
System.out.println("Value of b:-"+input); // shubham
input.reverse();
System.out.println("Value of b:-"+input); // mahbuhs
input.reverse();
System.out.println("Value of b:-"+input); // shubham
```

Do

```
String a = "shubham", reverse="";
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
input.append(a);

System.out.println("Value of a:-" + a);
System.out.println("Value of b:-" + input); 
input.reverse();

if(a.equals(input.toString())) {
    System.out.println("Given input is palidrome");
}else {
    System.out.println("Given input is not palidrome");
}
```